# copy width and height in addition to data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below code copies data(as well as formatting) from source range to target range.

```
Set RngTemplate = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A1:AD1")
Set RngTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("File1").Range("A1:AD1")   
RngTemplate.Copy RngTarget
```

But I also want the cell widths to be copied to target range, any idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.PasteSpecial()` method

```
Set RngTemplate = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A1:AD1")
Set RngTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("File1").Range("A1:AD1")   
RngTemplate.Copy
RngTarget.PasteSpecial
RngTarget.PasteSpeical xlPasteColumnWidths
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```